# CSS hover menu fly out menus

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/kvKfr/

Shows the menu as I've got it working. Does anyone know how to keep the LI element in the parent UL from expanding?  I want the sub menu to show to the right (as it is) with out causing the parent LI to change sizes.   Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea on these is to make the position absolute:

http://jsfiddle.net/kvKfr/1/

Comment: Just figured that out 30 seconds ago... can't answer my own question for 8 hours though. http://jsfiddle.net/kvKfr/7/

Answer (score 2):

Set

```
ul.myMenu li > ul
```

to be

```
position:absolute
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/kvKfr/2/